# Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $c\in[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity

Show there exists a sequence $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ converging to $c$ with $x_{n}\ne c$ for all $n$, such that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f'(x_{n})=f'(c)
$$

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this other than the following:

1. Show existence of $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$
2. Use the Mean value theorem and the sequential definition of continuity.

I guess I would start by establishing since $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, for any $x,y\in[a,b]$ we are guaranteed that for $c\in[a,b]$

$$
f(x)-f(y)=f'(c)(x-y)
$$

by the Mean value theorem. Furthermore, since $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ it is continuous. Therefore, by proposition (previously established elsewhere) we should be able to establish a sequence $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ in $[a,b]$ such that $\lim x_{n}=c$ and $f(\left\{x_{n}\right\})$ converges to $f(c)$.

Beyond that I would assume you use the definition of the derivative to establish that $f'(\left\{x_{n}\right\})$ converges to $f'(c)$.

This is the stuff I've been thinking about, but I haven't been able to pull it all together into a cohesive proof. Is there more that I am missing?

Comment: Try the following (c is fixed) : use the Mean value theorem on $[c,c+1/n]$ (or $[c-1/n,c]$) for every integer $n>0$. This will give you a $x_n \in (c,c+1/n)$ (or $(c-1/n,c))$ for every $n$. These $x_n$ are a good candidate for your problem

Comment: I will look into this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Wow, I guess I didn't see that before. I'll have a look into this, thanks!